# Solving the recurrence relation $T(n) = 2T(n^\frac{1}{2}) + c$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I've been trying to do this for hours. I just don't know how. I'm familiar with recurrence relations in the form of $T(\frac{n}{2})$, but what do you need to do to solve $T(n^\frac{1}{2})$?

I've assumed $T(1)$ and $c$ are constants. So this is when $n = 2$?

Comment: You should probably add the restriction that $n>1$, otherwise we get $T(1)=2T(\sqrt 1)+c$ which implies $c=-T(1)$. Because of the square root, it's more meaningful to start with $T(2)$ instead of $T(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Do the variable change $n = 2^{2^k}$, so you can take square roots every time. Your base case is $n = 2$, i.e., $k = 0$. You get a simple recurrence for $T(2^{2^k})$.

Comment: Or could you possibly expand on your answer? I'm not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

What vonbrand is suggesting is if you write $n=2^{2^k}$, then 
$$
\sqrt{n} = \sqrt{2^{2^k}}=(2^{2^k})^{1/2}=2^{2^{k-1}}
$$
so your recurrence may be written as
$$
T(2^{2^k})=2T(2^{2^{k-1}}) + c
$$
and we can do this substitution again (the blue part) to get
$$
\begin{align}
T(2^{2^k})&=2\;\color{#0000FF}{T(2^{2^{k-1}})} + c\\
&=2(\color{#0000FF}{2\;T(2^{2^{k-2}}) + c}) + c\\
&= 2^2T(2^{2^{k-2}})+2c + c
\end{align}
$$
If you continue doing these substitutions until you have the term $T(2^{2^0}) = T(2)$ (assuming you know $T(2)$. Note that $T(1)$ is no help here.), you'll have an equation with the $T$ term only on the left, and so will have a solution, in the form $T(2^{2^k}) =\ $ *some expression without any T's*, which is of course what you were looking for.

---

Here's another way to look at this problem. Instead of working from the top down, let's do it from bottom up to see if we can guess an answer.

We have
$$
T(2^{2^k})=2T(2^{2^{k-1}}) + c
$$
and let's call the value $T(2)=a$. Working up, we have
$$
\begin{align}
T(2^{2^0})=T(2) &= a\qquad\text{so}\\
T(2^{2^1})=T(4) &= 2T(\sqrt{4}) + c = 2T(2)+c = 2a+c\qquad\text{so}\\
T(2^{2^2})=T(16) &= 2T(4)+c = 2(2a+c)+c = 4a+2c+c\\
T(2^{2^3})=T(256) &= 2T(16)+c = 2(4a+2c+c)+c = 8a+4c+2c+c
\end{align}
$$
and we see a pattern developing:
$$
\begin{align}
T(2^{2^k}) &= 2^ka+2^{k-1}c+2^{k-2}c+\cdots + 2c+c\\
 &= 2^ka+(2^k-1)c
\end{align}
$$
Finally, we tidy this up a bit. Since we chose $n=2^{2^k}$, we'll have $\log_2n = 2^k$ so for those numbers, we can rewrite our guess as
$$
T(n) = (\log_2n)(T(2)+c)-c
$$
One final remark is in order. The solution we arrived at was a guess, based on the pattern we saw developing. To be rigorous, we should prove that our guess was right. This could be done by induction on $k$. It's not trivial, but it isn't all that difficult.

Comment: I don't know what T(2) is, but if I say  T(2^2k) = 2, then solve for k, i.e., k=1, then the result I reach is just 2. Is this correct?

Comment: @SexySarah I've added a section. Perhaps it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's set $R(k)=T(2^k)$. Substituting to the original formula we get
$$R(k)=T(2^k)=2T(\sqrt{2^k})+c=2T(2^{k/2})+c=2R(\frac{k}{2})+c.$$
The [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) tells us that $R(k)\in O(k)$. So let's try setting
$$R(k)=ak+b$$
and solve $a$ and $b$:
\begin{align}
ak+b &= 2(a\frac{k}{2}+b)+c \\
ak + b &= ak+2b+c \\
b &= - c \\
\end{align}
So $a$ can be arbitrary, and $T(n)=R(\log_2 n)=a\log_2 n - c$.